# Speeding up rspec controllers test: using before all fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2

I have a simple controller test, containing a.o. the following code:

```
context "POST :create" do
  before (:each) do
    post :create, :user_id => @user.id,
         :account => { .. some data ... }
  end
  it { response.status.should == 201 }
  it { response.location.should be_present }
end
```

Now I thought of a very simple way to speed up this test, and to use a `before(:all)` instead of a `before(:each)`. In that case the post would only be done once.

So i wrote:

```
context "POST :create" do
  before (:all) do
    post :create, :user_id => @user.id,
         :account => { .. some data ... }
  end
  it { response.status.should == 201 }
  it { response.location.should be_present }
end
```

But then I get the following errors:

```
 RuntimeError:
   @routes is nil: make sure you set it in your test's setup method.
```

Is this by design? Is there a way to circumvent it?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I've run into the same issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I asked this question on the rspec mailing list, and got the following reply from @dchelimsky himself:

> Yes. rspec-rails wraps the rails' testing framework which doesn't have a before(:all) concept in it, so all the data is reset before each example. Even if we wanted to support this in rspec-rails (which I don't) it would require changes to rails first.

So doing controller calls is not possible in a `before(:all)`, it can only be used to setup your DB or instance variables.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is a good idea, but setting a class variable with `||=` in the `before(:each)` block seems to work:

```
describe PagesController do
  describe "GET 'index'" do
    before(:each) do
      @@response ||= begin
        get :index
        response
      end
    end
    it { @@response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
    it { @@response.status.should == 301 }
    it { @@response.location.should be_present }
  end
end
```

## Update

Another potentially cleaner approach is to have multiple assertions in a single spec. Adding the `:aggregate_failures` tag (or wrapping the assertions in an `aggregate_failures {...}` block) will print each failure separately, which provides the granularity of separate tests:

```
describe PagesController do
  describe "GET 'index'" do
    it "redirects to homepage", :aggregate_failures do
       get :index
       expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)
       expect(response.status).to eq(301)
       expect(response.location).to be_present
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Did your try this? When I tested this the POST did not even work, because you are not yet in any controller context.

Comment: Oops, that was meant to say _haven't_ tried this. Updated answer with a different technique.

Comment: Now you do a `before(:each)` again, which is exactly what I wanted to avoid, and then there much prettier/readable ways to write it. If you do the `before :each` you can just write `get :index` and use `response`.

Comment: @nathanvda note the use of a class variable and `||=` - this should only execute the code the first time.

Comment: why was this not accepted as an answer? Can someone comment on if this is a good practice or not. It does seem to work

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go the dirty global variable way and benefit from the speeding increase, you can use this but *caution*. This messy logic does the job but defeats the purpose of driving with crystal clear readable tests. Refactoring in a helper with yield is more than recommended.

```
describe PagesController do
  describe "GET 'index'" do
    before(:each) do
      GLOBAL ||= {}
      @response = GLOBAL[Time.now.to_f] || begin
        get :index
        response
      end
    end
    it { @response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
    it { @response.status.should == 301 }
    it { @response.location.should be_present }
  end
end
```

The refactor you can put into a file of your choice in spec/support goes as follow

```
RSPEC_GLOBAL = {}

def remember_through_each_test_of_current_scope(variable_name)
  self.instance_variable_set("@#{variable_name}", RSPEC_GLOBAL[variable_name] || begin
    yield
  end)
  RSPEC_GLOBAL[variable_name] ||= self.instance_variable_get("@#{variable_name}")
end
```

Thus, the code in test file becomes :

```
describe PagesController do
  describe "GET 'index'" do
    before(:each) do
      remember_through_each_test_of_current_scope('memoized_response') do
        get :index
        response
      end
    end
    it { @memoized_response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
    it { @memoized_response.status.should == 301 }
    it { @memoized_response.location.should be_present }
  end
end
```

Hope it helps, and once again, use with caution